# SQL Update Statement using inner Join condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update a column in a  table CON for specific records based on the value from another table. So I need to use a join condition in update. I tried the below query but it does not work. Please help.

```
update S_CONTACT
SET CON.ACTIVE_FLG = 'N'
from S_CONTACT CON
INNER JOIN S_USER USR
ON CON.PAR_ROW_ID= USR.PAR_ROW_ID
where USR.LOGIN in('BJAME','GWOOD','HTRAME')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.)

Comment: Hi jarlh....Using Oracle DB. Yes..it is product specific.using it for crm product Siebel.

Comment: From what I remember, Oracle doesn't support UPDATE FROM.

Comment: Oh ok..I didnt know that. Is  there an alternative solution in my case ? I need to update a column with a join condition to fetch data from another table's column. Please let me know if you have know any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the alias on the set. You are already stating that you are updating `S_CONTACT`. This answer is for SQL-Server as you appear to be using syntax that is product specific. This syntax isn't valid in Oracle.

```
UPDATE S_CONTACT
SET ACTIVE_FLG = 'N'
FROM S_CONTACT CON
JOIN S_USER USR
ON CON.PAR_ROW_ID= USR.PAR_ROW_ID
WHERE USR.LOGIN in('BJAME','GWOOD','HTRAME')
```

For Oracle you can try the below:

```
UPDATE S_CONTACT
SET S_CONTACT.ACTIVE_FLG = 'N'
WHERE S_CONTACT.PAR_ROW_ID IN
        (SELECT CON.PAR_ROW_ID
        FROM S_CONTACT CON
        INNER JOIN S_USER USR
        ON CON.PAR_ROW_ID= USR.PAR_ROW_ID
        WHERE USR.LOGIN in('BJAME','GWOOD','HTRAME'))
```

Comment: Hi  ..I am using Oracle 12c.I tried removing alias in the SET  but still getting error.

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @Disha  Have you tried the `UPDATE` statement on this answer for Oracle syntax?

Comment: Thankyou so much MintBerryCRUNCH.The SQL which you provided worked.

Comment: @Disha Not a problem, if you could please accept my answer with the tick next to it that would be great. This is how you mark stackflow questions as answered.

Comment: I have accepted your answer MintBerryCRUNCH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs. The solution provided by MintBerryCRUNCH worked. Thank you so much MintBerryCRUNCH

For Oracle DB, below is the query:

```
UPDATE S_CONTACT 
SET S_CONTACT.ACTIVE_FLG = 'N' 
WHERE S_CONTACT.PAR_ROW_ID IN (
  SELECT CON.PAR_ROW_ID 
  FROM S_CONTACT CON 
  INNER JOIN S_USER USR 
  ON CON.PAR_ROW_ID= USR.PAR_ROW_ID 
  WHERE USR.LOGIN in('BJAME','GWOOD','HTRAME')
)
```

Comment: Accept MintBerryCRUNCH's answer by clicking on the checkmark and then delete this answer because it adds nothing new. Take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-can-i-accept-an-answer-and-which-one-should-i-choose